# why mysql where provide result with alphanumeric value?

Tags: mysql

When I filter numeric id with where condition inside with key all then result is like this which is correct https://prnt.sc/1ubkviy

But when we pass alpha numeric value inside where condition, still it is giving result then can you explain us in detail why this is happening https://prnt.sc/1ubkzbq

Comment: id is INT ? because if yes, mysql will convert string into int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **BINARY** for exact match:

```
SELECT * FROM office_category WHERE BINARY id="2sssss"
```